# How can I display a spinner in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, callback, spinner

I have a React App and I want to show a spinner when processing will take some time to complete, for example an API request, or even lengthy setting of state. I have tried a callback such as:

```
                this.setState({
                    showSpinner: true,
                }, () =>
                    this.APIgiveMeTheWorld().then(
                        this.setState({
                            showSpinner: false,
                        })
                    ));
```

and async function with:

```
                await this.setState({
                    showSpinner: true,
                });
                this.APIgiveMeTheWorld().then(
                    await this.setState({
                        showSpinner: false,
                    })
                );
```

But at no discernible point does state show **showSpinner** as being true (therefore my spinner never appears). What is the best way to implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: I see first one may be correct. Could you give more detail about how to show `Spinner`?

Comment: Hi Viet Dinh, showSpinner is used in the render function to add or remove a 'show' class, CSS should do the rest.

Comment: Did it Like? <Spinner className={this.state.showSpinner ? 'show' : null}

Comment: Yes Viet, but it's not the show/hide code that's at issue, I cannot see showSpinner change in programmers tools even. It is some sort of timing issue.

Comment: Yes, let try my comment.

Comment: It's a little bizarre, I knocked up this CodePen https://codepen.io/GusTButt/pen/YzybJKR?editors=1111 which works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with my API function resolving instantaneously.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, it should be closed!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to show the Spinner as long the `showSpinner` state is false and hide it when It became false

```
{ !showSpinner? <SpinnerComponent /> : <ResultShower /> }
```

And in your component you can load your data from an API in the `componentWillMount` lifeCycle and when the loading completed and you have data back from the API's Call you can update the `showSpinner` state to false, which will automatically hide the `SpinnerComponent` and show whatever else you want to show.

```
componentWillMount() {
    loadData().then((data) => {

        // Here I consider get data from from you API request

        this.setState({
           data,
           showSpinner: false
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yves, but even in programmers tools, state never changes discernibly. How to show/hide isn't an issue, it's the timing seemingly.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have passed result of setState in call back `then`. Did you try:

```
this.setState({
    showSpinner: true,
}, () =>
    //should pass a call back function to call right after api return.
    this.APIgiveMeTheWorld().then(r => {
        this.setState({
            showSpinner: false,
        })
    }));
```